# getting values and keys in separate arrays sorted by values

Tags: javascript, object

Suppose I have an object `{'a':20,'b':6,'c':21,'d':12}`

After getting sort by values in descending order,
The desired output : `Keys: ['c','a','d','b']` and `Values: [21,20,12,6]`

How can I achieve that efficiently? I came to knew that we cannot we cant sort js object keys based on values, since the order of keys is random everytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I came to knew that we cannot we cant sort js object keys based on values, since the order of keys is random everytime.

That's not true (it's not random, and it's not different every time), but sorting JavaScript *objects* is almost never useful.

You have several options to get the array you've shown. One simple one is to use `Object.entries` to get an array of `[key, value]` arrays, then `sort` that, then get just the keys from it via `map`:

```js
const obj = {'a':20,'b':6,'c':21,'d':12};
const keys = Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v2 - v1)
    .map(([k, v]) => k);
console.log(keys);
```

`Object.entries` is relatively new, but easily polyfilled if needed.

If you need it in ES5 (with `Object.entries` polyfilled):

```js
var obj = {'a':20,'b':6,'c':21,'d':12};
var keys = Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(function(e1, e2) {
        return e2[1] - e1[1];
    })
    .map(function(e) {
        return e[0];
    });
console.log(keys);
```

---

In a comment you've asked how to have the values in a separate array as well. You can either build that value array as a side-effect of `map` by pushing into it, like this:

```js
const obj = {'a':20,'b':6,'c':21,'d':12};
const values = [];
const keys = Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v2 - v1)
    .map(([k, v]) => {
        values.push(v);
        return k;
    });
console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

...or if using `map` for side-effects bothers you (it's often not best practice), just use `forEach` (or `for-of`) instead:

```js
const obj = {'a':20,'b':6,'c':21,'d':12};
const keys = [];
const values = [];
Object.entries(obj)
    .sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v2 - v1)
    .forEach(([k, v]) => {
        keys.push(k);
        values.push(v);
    });
console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

The `for-of` version:

```js
const obj = {'a':20,'b':6,'c':21,'d':12};
const keys = [];
const values = [];
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(obj).sort(([k1, v1], [k2, v2]) => v2 - v1)) {
    keys.push(k);
    values.push(v);
}
console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

*(You might use a temporary variable for the result of `.sort`, then use `for (const [k, v] of theTemporaryVariable) {`.)*

Comment: Sir how can I get the values in a separate array? @T.J.

Comment: @BinayakGS - You want to have a `keys` array and a parallel `values` array?

Comment: Yes. That's where I am facing blockage.

Comment: @BinayakGS - Added that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = {'a':20,'b':6,'c':21,'d':12};

const result = Object.keys(obj)
  .reduce((acc, key) => {
    const value = obj[key];
    acc.push({ key, value });
    acc.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
    return acc;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

output

```js
[
  { key: 'c', value: 21 },
  { key: 'a', value: 20 }
  { key: 'd', value: 12 }
  { key: 'b', value: 6 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const list = {'a':20,'b':6,'c':21,'d':12};

let myObject = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(list).sort( (a,b) => b[1] - a[1] ));

Object.prototype.mySplit = function() {
  return Object.keys(this).map((key) => {
    return {
      key: key,
      value: this[key]
    };
  });
}

let keys = [];
let values = [];

let properties = myObject.mySplit();
for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    keys.push(properties[i]['key']);
    values.push(properties[i]['value']);
}

console.log(keys);
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Get keys from an object

2) Sort keys based on val comparision

```
function cmp(a, b) {
  return (a < b) ? 1 : (a > b) ? -1 : 0
}

function sortObj(obj) {
   const keys = Object.keys(obj).sort((x,y) => cmp(obj[x],obj[y]))
   const vals = keys.map(x => obj[x])
   return {sortedKeys: keys, sortedValues: vals}
}

result = sortObj({'a':20,'b':6,'c':21,'d':12})
console.log(result)
```

Answer

```
{
sortedKeys:  ["c", "a", "d", "b"]
sortedValues: [21, 20, 12, 6]
}
```